# Borel probability measure vs Probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-measures

Is there a difference between these two terminologies?

1. space of all Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R^n$ or some complete, separable metric space.
2. space of all Probability measure on $\mathbb R^n$ or some complete, separable metric space.

In other words, what would be differences in the definitions of a Borel probability measure and a probability measure on the above mentioned spaces.

Thanks for explaining to me.

Comment: For $\mathbb R^n$, when the sigma-algebra is not mentioned, we should assume the Borel sets.  So these are the same.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2) the sigma-algebra is not specified.

In 1) the sigma-algebra is the sigma-algebra of all Borel sets, the one generated by open sets.